# TFS2015 Build failed email notifications are missing errors

Tags: email, tfs, notifications, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

In 2013 XAML Builds, email notifications about failed builds used to have a nice overview of the errors occurred in the Summary.
For example, when there was a compilation error in one file, this file and the error were displayed.

In 2015 Update 1, there were only red "**():**" in place of the errors and since Update 2 they are lacking completely, saying 0 Errors in the Build summary but "Build failed" in the subject.

If you open the builds in Web Access the errors are displayed as they should.

Is there any way to restore the Build Error Messages?

Comment: Hi Suchiman, we have a bug tracking this.  It's assigned to a developer and it's currently targeting VSTS and next release of TFS (Dev15)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I could reproduce your issue on my side. Email alerts can generate the error messages for XAML build, but only shows `0 error(s), 0 warning(s)` for a fail vNext build:

[image]

As we can't modify email alerts' content. You need to submit a feedback at website http://connect.microsoft.com/visualstudio.

Comment: After more tests, I've found this issue only happens at Build step. If there is a Test step fails, the email alert generates correct information.

Comment: I feared to be redirected to connect... created https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2694949

Comment: We have a bug tracking and a dev is looking at it.

Comment: Verified to be fixed in TFS 2015 Update 3!

Comment: Still encountering TFS 2015 Update 3 on prem. Can't connect to the old bug detail link above. Failed vNext build Summary still showing "0 error(s), 0 warning(s)"